# Issues counting strings in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i am trying to create a macro that will loop through my worksheet and find a specific string of text. Once if has found that string i want it to look to the column next to it and  if it says PoweredOn or PoweredOff then add 1 to a counter then display the number at the end.

in my excel i have column A as my virtual machines and in column B is the power state I have a loop setup to look for one virtual machine that is a template and is powered on but when i run my macro it prints it as 0 here is my code at the moment.

```
Dim POT As Integer
Dim POFFT As Integer
Sheets("tabvInfo").Select
Range("A2").Select

Do
If ActiveCell.Value = ("vCloud Cell Template") Then
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ("PoweredOn") Then
    POT = Selection.Cell.Count

Else
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ("PoweredOff") Then
    POFFT = Selection.Cell.Count
    End If
    End If
    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select


 Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))

MsgBox ("The number of powerered on VMs is " & POT)
MsgBox ("The number of powerered off VMs is " & POFFT)
```

Can anyone tell me why i am getting 0 as the result? I also need to make this look at other templates on my system while retaining the count of values would i need to create a do loop for each template or can i use an array to do this?

Comment: So the cells in column A can only contain `"vCloud Cell Template"` or `""`?

Comment: Yes i only wanted it to count the cells that contained the full string    .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
Sub Main()
    Dim POT As Long
    Dim POFFT As Long

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("tabvInfo").Range("A2:A" & Sheets("tabvInfo").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If StrComp(c, "vCloud Cell Template", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            If StrComp(c.Offset(0, 1), "PoweredOn", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                POT = POT + 1
            ElseIf StrComp(c.Offset(0, 1), "PoweredOff", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                POFFT = POFFT + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox ("The number of powerered on VMs is " & POT)
    MsgBox ("The number of powerered off VMs is " & POFFT)
End Sub
```

It eliminates the `.Select` statement and `.ActiveCell`. It's a simple for loop that achieves what you want.

---

I am not sure you realize but you can achieve this using 2 very simple formulas for PoweredOn and Off

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"vCloud Cell Template",B:B, "PoweredOn")
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"vCloud Cell Template",B:B, "PoweredOFF")
```

---

Therefore to eliminate the need for using a loop you can

```
Sub NoLoop()
    MsgBox "Powered ON: " & Evaluate("=COUNTIFS(A:A,""vCloud Cell Template"",B:B, ""PoweredOn"")")
    MsgBox "Powered OFF: " & Evaluate("=COUNTIFS(A:A,""vCloud Cell Template"",B:B, ""PoweredOff"")")
End Sub
```

Comment: You could also put the two formula "on sheet" to have them constantly updated without needing any VBA.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald I thought that was obvious since I actually listed `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"vCloud Cell Template",B:B, "PoweredOn")` but I guess it may be helpful to some future visitors so +1 for your comment :)